# Naming worksheets in a loop VBA

Tags: vba, loops, excel

I am trying to **name worksheets** based on a list of names in **Sheets("Run").Range("F4")**  to last row with Data. The code i have below works when i am naming one worksheet.

```
Sub list_Days()


Dim sName As String
Dim i As Integer
i = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

sName = Sheets("Run").Range("F4")

Worksheets("Security Distribution").Copy After:=Worksheets(i)
ActiveSheet.Name = sName

End Sub
```

**My Question:** Can someone assist me  with an **effective loop** which will overcome my problem .

Comment: There was a pre-existing `Rows.Count` not `Row.Count` issue with the solution in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30426074/name-worksheets-based-on-a-list-of-names/30426261#30426261) which you had remarked that you had resolved. I've edited the answer to reflect `Rows.Count`.

Comment: Thanks alot for that. The answer was effective in that scenario , but its not working in the other  macro i am running now. If i apply the answer above i     am getting the wrong naming .

Comment: The above will work the first time but you have to redefine *i* the second time around as it is no longer equal to the count of the worksheets. Each time you add another worksheet and name it, *i* must be raised by *1* or reassigned with `i = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count`.

Comment: You can't have multiple sheets with the same name

Comment: @Jeeped thanks that's solved now

Answer (score 0):

This should be a simple `for x = y to z` loop with an increment in the target range (assuming the rest of the code works as expected) -

```
Sub list_Days()

Dim sName As Range
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
i = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
j = 0
sName = Sheets("Run").Range("F4")


 For x = 1 To i
 Set sName = sName.Offset(j, 0)
 Worksheets("Security Distribution").Copy After:=Worksheets(x)
 ActiveSheet.Name = sName.Value
 j = j + 1
 Next

End Sub
```